# Writing A Cipher Program

Tags: c, encryption

Write a program (a filter) that reads a stream of ASCII from standard input
 and sends characters to standard output. The program discards all characters other
 than letters. Any lowercase letter is output as an uppercase letter.
 Output characters in groups of five separated by a space character. Output a newline
 character after every 10 groups. (The last group on a line is followed only by newline;
 the last group on a line does not have a space after it.) The very last group of all may
 have fewer than five characters, and the last line may have fewer than 10 groups. Assume that the input file is a text file of arbitrary length. Use getchar() and
 putchar() for this. You will never need to have more than one character of input data
 in memory at one time

What I am having trouble with is how do do the spacing. I created an array with 5 objects but I don't dont what to do with it. This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char c=0, block[4]; 

    while (c != EOF)
    {
       c=getchar();

       if (isupper(c))
       {
           putchar(c);
       }
       if (islower(c))
       {
          putchar(c-32);
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: smells like homework...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    char c=0; 
    int charCounter = 0;
    int groupCounter = 0;

    while (c != EOF)
    {
       c=getchar();

       if (isupper(c))
       {
           putchar(c);
           charCounter++;
       }
       if (islower(c))
       {
          putchar(c-32);
          charCounter++;
       }

       // Output spaces and newlines as specified.
       // Untested, I'm sure it will need some fine-tuning.
       if (charCounter == 5)
       {
           putchar(' ');
           charCounter = 0;
           groupCounter++;
       }

       if (groupCounter == 10)
       {
           putchar('\n');
           groupCounter = 0;
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: the OP will never learn how to create an algorithm if you give him the answer as is.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to store characters in order to perform the algorithm described in your question.

you should read one character at a time, and keep track of 2 counters that i won't disclose. each counter will allow you to know where to put the special characters needed to format the output.

basically:

```
read a character
if the character is valid for output then
   convert it to uppercase if needed
   output the character
   update the counters
   output space and or newlines according to the counters
end if
```

hope this helps.

*additionally: i don't know what you tried to do with the `block` variable, but it is declared as an array of 4 elements, and nowhere in the text is the number 4 used...*