# Assembly Language Addition

Tags: assembly, addition, opcode, hex, 8051

I am new to assembly language and I found this table of hex codes that I need http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/is51/is51_opcodes.htm  But my question is does it matter which "ADD" instruction I do given a certain situation since they range from 24-2F or can I just pick anyone I desire?

Comment: The different encodings are for adding different things. Look at the fourth column.

Comment: You haven't upvoted any answers on your prior questions, or accepted any answers.   You won't get much help if you don't Upvote and Accept answers provided.  (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713346/writing-a-cipher-program)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to choose the one that mathches what you want to accomplish, i.e., how the value you want to add is specified. Do you for instance want to add an immediate operand or a value in a register? As stated by Raymond Chen, the details are present in the fourth column.

Comment: Ok Thanks,  I just figured out the register system.  Makes a lot more sense now :)

Comment: If it helped answering your question, don't forget to mark it as solved (click the check box of the answer). This helps people see what questions have been answered.